# Abnormal card spacing

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When I click on the card, the space between the top and bottom of the card increases

[orignial card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjzLQ.png)

[click once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPp0s.png)

[click twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck1vt.png)

```swift
struct CardView: View {
    // String -> MemoryGame<String>.Card
    let card: MemoryGame<String>.Card
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20.0)
            if card.isFaceUp {
                shape.fill(.white)
                shape.strokeBorder(lineWidth: 3)
                Text(card.content) // I think the root of the problem may be here
                    .font(.largeTitle)
            } else if card.isMatched {
                shape.opacity(0.0)
            } else {
                shape.fill()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: EmojiMemoryGame
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Memorize!")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            Group {
                Text(viewModel.themeName)
                    .font(.subheadline)
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 75))]) {
                        ForEach(viewModel.cards) { card in
                            CardView(card: card)
                                .aspectRatio(2/3, contentMode: .fit)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    viewModel.choose(card)
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .foregroundColor(viewModel.theme.uiColor)
            .padding(.horizontal)
            
//            Spacer()
            
            Button {
                viewModel.startNewGame()
            } label: {
                Text("New Game")
                    .font(.title)
            }
            
            Text("Score: \(viewModel.score)")
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to analyze every detail of the code, and I found that the problem was probably in the CardView when the card was facing up, it was showing an extra Text that was causing an exception

Comment: Try removing the borderWidth and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Text element has its own frame and when added on top of the shape in this ZStack causes the frame of the whole stack to expand a little bit which is why you're seeing this problem.
One quick and easy solution to this would be to remove the frame of the Text element with this modifier:

```
.frame(height: .zero)
```

which would look like this:

```
struct CardView: View {
// String -> MemoryGame<String>.Card
let card: MemoryGame<String>.Card

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20.0)
        if card.isFaceUp {
            shape.fill(.white)
            shape.strokeBorder(lineWidth: 3)
            Text(card.content) // I think the root of the problem may be here
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .frame(height: .zero)
        } else if card.isMatched {
            shape.opacity(0.0)
        } else {
            shape.fill()
        }
    }
}
```